# How to get last created product id?

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, importexport

I have overridden the `Mage_ImportExport_Model_Import_Entity_Abstract` class and in the function  `_saveValidatedBunches()` I want to get the last created product Id. I've tried the following, but it returns null.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$latestItemId = $collection->getLastItem()->getId();
```

Comment: you can check magento function getLastItem at lib\Varien\Data\Collection.php

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can try like below with latest `created_at`

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                    ->getCollection()                   
                    ->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'desc');   

   $collection->getSelect()->limit(1);
```

**EDIT**

```
  echo $latestItemId = $collection->getLastItem()->getId();
  exit;
```

hope this will sure help you.

Comment: @liyakat: Thanks a lot :) and +1, Your answer worked perfectly. I'll accept it

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
$collection->addAttributeToSort('entity_id', 'DESC');
$collection->setPage(1,1); //set a limit to 1 so the query would be faster
echo $collection->getFirstItem()->getId();
```

Comment: Marius: it will gives first not last created.

Comment: @AmitKamboj. Yep. You are right. I will come up with an other solution in a few moments. Looks like `getAllIds`  resets the order.

Comment: Change the answer to a working solution.

Comment: Yes Marius i have checked its working :)

Comment: Thanks a lot Marius. As always your answer worked :) and +1

Answer (score 1):

This will sort products by create date desc:

```
$todayDate  = Mage::app()->getLocale()->date()->toString(Varien_Date::DATETIME_INTERNAL_FORMAT);

$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                    ->getCollection()                   
                    ->addAttributeToFilter('news_from_date', array('date' => true, 'to' => $todayDate))
                    ->addAttributeToFilter('news_to_date', array('or'=> array(
                        0 => array('date' => true, 'from' => $todayDate),
                        1 => array('is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('null')))
                    ), 'left')
                    ->addAttributeToSort('news_from_date', 'desc')
                    ->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'desc');
```

Then limit it to one to get the last created:

```
$collection->getSelect()->limit(1);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, But if I took first item in the collection or last item id, it returns null. I tried with `$collection->getLastItem()->getId();` and `$collection->getFirstItem()->getId();`. But both are null